# Mostrar contador solo cuando llegue a la seccion js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy haciendo un contador de números con jQuery, hasta ahí todo bien. El problema está en que solo quiero que se ejecute cuando llegues a la sección, porque si no, cuando bajas y llegas ya se ha completado la función. Lo he intentado con el `delay` pero lo único que he conseguido es darle unos segundos de margen.

Éste es el código que tengo (en [Codepen](https://codepen.io/adrifa98/pen/KJzQKz)):

```js
$('.counter').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    countTo = $this.attr('data-count');

  $({
    countNum: $this.text()
  }).animate({
      countNum: countTo
    },

    {
      duration: 8000,
      easing: 'linear',
      step: function() {
        $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
      },
      complete: function() {
        $this.text(this.countNum);
        //alert('finished');
      }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #F46A6A;
  color: #fff;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
}

.counter {
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 1.5%;
  font-size: 50px;
  background-color: #FF6F6F;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 150%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="texto">
  <p>baja</p><br>
  <div class="counter" data-count="150">0</div>
  <div class="counter" data-count="85">0</div>
  <div class="counter" data-count="2200">0</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  $('.text').each(function(){
    if(isScrolledIntoView($(this))){
      $(this).children('span').text('visible');
    }
    else{
      $(this).children('span').text('invisible');
    }
  });
});

function isScrolledIntoView(elem){
    var $elem = $(elem);
    var $window = $(window);

    var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height();

    var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
```

Comment: Agrega una explicación de lo que realizaría el código, revisa [answer].

Answer (score 1):

Una cosa que podrías hacer para no cambiar mucho tu código es poner la parte que  inicia los contadores  dentro de una función y sólo llamar a esa función cuando los  contadores estén visibles.

Para ello los pasos serían:

- Envuelve tu código en una función (yo la he llamado `empezarContadores`)
- Añade una controlador del evento scroll a la ventana que:

  1. compruebe si el scroll supera la parte superior del elemento que contiene los contadores (`.text`). Para esto puedes usar `scrollTop()` para saber cuánto se han movido los scrolls y `offset()` (con la opción  `top`) para saber la posición vertical de un elemento.
  2. Si el elemento está visible (dentro del área visible de la ventana): llama a la función que creaste arriba.

Para completarlo, puedes quitar el controlador del evento `scroll` usando `off` (para que sea más eficiente porque no se estarán haciendo comprobaciones cada vez que se haga scroll).

Aquí puedes ver los cambios de arriba funcionando:

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function(){
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(".texto").offset().top) {
    empezarContadores();
    $(window).off("scroll");
  }
})

function empezarContadores() {
  $('.counter').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      countTo = $this.attr('data-count');
    $({
      countNum: $this.text()
    }).animate({
        countNum: countTo
      },

      {
        duration: 8000,
        easing: 'linear',
        step: function() {
          $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
        },
        complete: function() {
          $this.text(this.countNum);
          //alert('finished');
        }
      });
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #F46A6A;
  color: #fff;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
}

.counter {
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 1.5%;
  font-size: 50px;
  background-color: #FF6F6F;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 150%;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
max-height: 100px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="texto">
  <p>baja</p><br>
  <div class="counter" data-count="150">0</div>
  <div class="counter" data-count="85">0</div>
  <div class="counter" data-count="2200">0</div>
</div>
```